# How do I Solve Express Validator Middleware Error?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

First, I have userController like this:

**File userController.js**

```
const { validationResults } = require('express-validator');
const { userSignUpValidation } = require('../validator/userSignUpValidate');


function userCreation(req, res) {
    try{
        const errors = validationResults(req);
        if(errors) {
            return res.status(400)
            .json({
                error: {
                    message: errors.array()[0].msg
                }
            })
        }

        bcrypt.hash(req.body.userPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
            User.create({
                userId: req.body.userId,
                userEmail: req.body.userEmail,
                userPhoneNumber: req.body.userPhoneNumber,
                userPassword: hash
            })
            .then((user) => {
                return res.status(200).json(user);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                return res.status(400).json.error;
            });
        });
    } catch(error) {
        return res.status(400)
        .json({
            error: {
                message: error
            }
        })
    }
}
```

In the **validator/userSignUpValidate.js** the code like this:

```
'use strict'

const { check } = require('express-validator');

module.exports = [
    check('userId').isLength({ min: 5 }).withMessage('The username at least more than 5 characters!'),
    check('userPassword').isLength({ min: 6 }).withMessage('The password at least more than 6 characters!'),
    check('userPhoneNumber').isLength({ min: 10 }).withMessage('The phone number at least more than 10 characters!'),
    check('userEmail').isEmail().withMessage('Is your email correct? Please be correct!')
]
```

When I test it on postman, the json response always show error by `catch` on userController.js without error message.

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": {}
    }
}
```

My question. To ensure the express-validator run in the right place, where should I put the code?

Comment: check my below updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to import `validationResult` from `express-validator`, in your code you are importing `validationResults`.

Secondly, you are not using your `userSignUpValidate` middleware. This middleware can be used in controller but it is better to appy it in the userRoute to keep controller clean.

So let's apply `userSignUpValidate` middleware to the userRoutes.
If the file paths don't match yours, please fix them.

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const usersController = require("../controllers/userController");
const userSignUpValidate = require("../validator/userSignUpValidate");

router.post("/register", [userSignUpValidate], usersController.userCreation);

module.exports = router;
```

Then in the controller, we need to import `validationResult` from `express-validator` and use it:

```js
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");

function userCreation(req, res) {
  try {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
      console.log(errors);
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: {
          message: errors.array()[0].msg
        }
      });
    }

    //other code you have
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: {
        message: error
      }
    });
  }
}

exports.userCreation = userCreation;
```

When we send a request body with a 3 character password like this:

```
{
  "userId": "userid",
  "userPassword": "123",
  "userPhoneNumber": "1234567890",
  "userEmail": "abc@gmail.com"
}
```

The response will be like this with a 400 - Bad Request:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "The password at least more than 6 characters!"
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer work for me. After following this guide, I just need to change some minor syntax according the https://express-validator.github.io/docs/index.html. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ZapraGartiast you are welcome, what syntax needed to be changed? Because I tried this code, and it worked.

Comment: I change the `if(errors)` to `if(!errors.isEmpty)`.

Comment: @ZapraGartiast yes better to use like in the docs, but both of them work as expected. In your code it was like that so I didn't changed that part.

Comment: Update! If you use `if(errors)` then you submit non-errors value, you will get `{ "error": { "message": {} } }`. I guess you need to update your answer to help others when using your code as reference.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass  like this

`const errors = validationResults(req.body);`

Comment: It's said `validationResults is not a function`

Comment: yes because validationResults is not a function you have just used to require express-validator ,

Comment: pass array in userSignUpValidation  to run your validation

Answer (score 0):

```
 const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');                                           
 const loginValidation = data =>{    const schema = {
    username: Joi.string().min(5).required(),
    password: Joi.string().min(5).required(),
    deviceId: Joi.string().min(2).required()
};
return Joi.validate(data, schema); };                   
module.exports.loginValidation = loginValidation;
```

> My Routes File

```
const { registerValidation, loginValidation } = require('../../validation');   router.post('/login', async (req, res)=>{
try {
    //validate the data to be submitted
    const { error } = loginValidation(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(200).send(
        {
            status: 0,
            message: "Validarion Error",
            details: error.details[0].message
        });

} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send({
        status: 0,
        message: "Failed",
        error: error
    });
}});
```

this code works fine and is in production mode

Comment: @code_B he is using express-validator not @hapi/joi. Can you pls check your answer again.

Comment: It's good if you're not pass the function to the router. Since my router file like this: `router.post('/create', userController.userCreation);`

Comment: yes i have done validation like this you can use this its easy to code with hapi. and if you want to do it with express validator check this https://morioh.com/p/958925559f2b

Answer (score 0):

Just try like below,

```
const express = require('express');
const { check, oneOf, validationResult } = require('express-validator');


const app = express();

//this function you need to export in controller
const xxx = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    validationResult(req).throw();
    res.status(200).send('success');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error messagecame')
    res.status(422).json(err);
  }
}

app.get('/', oneOf([
  check('lang').isIn(['js', 'react', 'angular'])
]), xxx);

app.listen(4000, ()=>{
  console.log("running server 4k")
})
```

[Sample working copy](https://repl.it/repls/FickleBoldContent)

## UPDATE 2

I hope below one will help full,

```
const express = require('express');
const { check, oneOf, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const app = express();
const xxx = [
  check('lang').isIn(['js', 'react', 'angular']),
  (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      validationResult(req).throw();
      res.status(200).send('success');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error messagecame')
      res.status(422).json(err);
    }
  }
]

app.get('/', xxx);

app.listen(4000, ()=>{
  console.log("running server 4k")
})
```

[SAMPLE WORKING COPY2](https://repl.it/repls/TruthfulWeirdIrc)

## Error

https://TruthfulWeirdIrc--five-nine.repl.co?lang=jssddf

## Success

https://TruthfulWeirdIrc--five-nine.repl.co?lang=js

Comment: My problem, the function `userCreation` is passed to router like this `router.post('/create', userController.userCreation);` that's why I'm a bit confused, because the project wanted to be modular.